# pass an index to the method reduce() laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this function created to show a piechart but I need each element to show a different color. For this I have created an array with all the colors and I need in each iteration of the reduce() method to have an index to access the colors[i]. I have tried this way and it does not work. Any suggestion?

```
$i = 0;
$pieChartModel = $options->groupBy('survey_options_id')
    ->reduce(function (PieChartModel $pieChartModel, $data) use ($i) {
        $type = $data->first()->survey_options_id;
        $value = $data->sum('value');
        // $color = "#" . substr(md5(rand()), 0, 6);
        $NameOption = Survey_options::where('id', $type)->pluck('name');

        return $pieChartModel->addSlice($NameOption, $value, $this->colors[$i]->hexa);
        $i++;
    }, (new PieChartModel())->setAnimated($this->firstRun)->setDataLabelsEnabled(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem I'm seeing in your code is how you're incrementing `$i` **AFTER** a return statement.

After taking a look at the source code for the `reduce()` function

> ```
>     /**
>      * Reduce the collection to a single value.
>      *
>      * @param  callable  $callback
>      * @param  mixed $initial
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function reduce(callable $callback, $initial = null)
>     {
>         $result = $initial;
>
>         foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
>             $result = $callback($result, $value, $key);
>         }
>
>         return $result;
>     }
> ```

You should be able to use the key (or index) in the callback.

```php
->reduce(function ($carry, $item, $key) { ... }, $initial)
```

```php
->reduce(function (PieChartModel $pieChartModel, $data, $i) {
        ...
    }, (new PieChartModel())->setAnimated($this->firstRun)->setDataLabelsEnabled(true))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting an error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Livewire\FrontEnd\PieChart::App\Http\Livewire\FrontEnd\{closure}(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected (View: C:\laragon\www\doogmas\resources\views\public\show.blade.php)